# groupby summarise outside of groupby dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to group ids with date in this dataset, but I want to summarise based on one of the features outside of the group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(ids = sample(c('436247', '2465347', '346654645'), 10000, replace=TRUE),
                 date = sample(seq.Date(ymd('2018-03-01'), ymd('2018-05-01'), by=1), 10000, replace=TRUE))

new_df <- df %>%
    group_by(ids, date) %>%
    summarise(events = length(ids[date >= date - 30 & date <= date]))
```

I'm trying to take this dataframe and answer the question - "for each of the ids, and each date, how many other records within that id, are within the past 30 days of that date". Unfortunately, when I `group_by` both the ids and date, it only looks within the grouped date. I've created the solution below, but not sure if there is a better one with dplyr?

```
groupby_function <- function(df, spec_date){
  result <- df %>%
      group_by(ids) %>%
      summarise(events = length(ids[date >= spec_date - 30 & date <= spec_date])) %>%
      mutate(date = spec_date)
  return(result)

} 

date_vector <- seq.Date(ymd('2018-03-01'), ymd('2018-05-01'), by=1)
list_results <- lapply(date_vector, groupby_function, df=df)
x <- do.call(rbind, list_results)
```

Answer (score 1):

> "for each of the ids, and each date, how many other records within that id, are within the past 30 days of that date"

For that, a "join by" condition makes sense, but [isn't yet included in dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2240). Until it is, you could use data.table inside your dplyr chain:

```
# enumerate id-date combos of interest
grid_df = expand.grid(
  id = unique(df$ids), 
  d = seq(min(df$date), max(df$date), by="day")
)

# helper function
library(data.table)
count_matches = function(DF, targetDF, ...){
  onexpr = substitute(list(...))
  data.table(targetDF)[DF, on=eval(onexpr), .N, by=.EACHI]$N
}

# use a non-equi join to count matching rows
res = grid_df %>% 
  mutate(d_dn = d - 30) %>% 
  mutate(n = count_matches(., df, ids = id, date >= d_dn, date <= d)) %>% 
  as.tibble

# A tibble: 186 x 4
          id          d       d_dn     n
      <fctr>     <date>     <date> <int>
 1    436247 2018-03-01 2018-01-30    72
 2   2465347 2018-03-01 2018-01-30    69
 3 346654645 2018-03-01 2018-01-30    51
 4    436247 2018-03-02 2018-01-31   123
 5   2465347 2018-03-02 2018-01-31   120
 6 346654645 2018-03-02 2018-01-31   100
 7    436247 2018-03-03 2018-02-01   170
 8   2465347 2018-03-03 2018-02-01   166
 9 346654645 2018-03-03 2018-02-01   154
10    436247 2018-03-04 2018-02-02   228
# ... with 176 more rows
```

It should work fine for equality conditions to write either `ids = id` or `ids == id`, I think.

If you're interested, the syntax is `x[i, on=, j, by=.EACHI]` where `x` and `i` are tables. For each row of `i`, we look up rows of `x` based on the `on=` criteria (left-hand side refers to columns in `x`; right-hand to columns in `i`); then we do `j` for each ("by each row of `i`" so `by=.EACHI`). In this case, `j = .N` means that we count matched rows of `x`, returned as a column of counts `N`.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the "ungrouped" data by just going back to the original data frame(calling `df$date` or `df$ids`).  So I *think* what you are after is

```
test_df <- df %>%
  group_by(ids, date) %>%
  summarise(events = length(df$ids[df$date >= date[1] - 30 & df$date <= date[1] & df$ids == ids[1]]))
```

Also, I ran your proposed function, but I did not see any difference in the result from your original `group_by` solution, so I don't think that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll test it out. Now does this date filter stay within the id? Or will this produce a vector of the line items that have dates within 30 days, but of varying ids?

Comment: varying ids, as I coded it originally. I added `df$ids == id[1]` as part of the condition to only get the dates within 30 days of the same id

Answer (score 0):

If a 'non dplyr' solution is acceptable, this gives you what you want.

```
df$diff <- as.vector(
  sapply(unique(df$ids), function(x)
    sapply(df$date[df$ids == x], function(y)
      sum(abs(y - df$date[df$ids == x]) >= 30)
      )
    )
  )
```

Alternatively, in `dplyr`, you can get a result like the above using:

```
f <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(y) sum(abs(y - x) >= 30))
  }

df$diff <- unlist(
  df %>%
    group_by(ids) %>%
    do(diff = f(.$date)) %>%
    .$diff
  )
```

Comment: I don't believe this one works correctly, or at least maybe I didn't describe clearly what I was looking for. For example, there are multiple rows where the id and date are the same. say 436247 and 2018-03-01, and the diff calculation differs. It should always be the same, and ideally there should only be one line (since this would be a groupby summarise)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer. But it assumes there's a continuous sequence of dates in each `id`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(ids, date) %>%
  count() %>%
  arrange(ids, date) %>%
  group_by(ids) %>%
  mutate(
    events = cumsum(n) - cumsum(lag(n, 30, 0))
  )
```