# Expand groups between two values and count unique occurences

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this table

```
> data.frame(user = c("x", "y"), item = c("a", "a"), level = c(1, 1), level_max = c(2, 4))
  user item level level_max
1    x    a     1         2
2    y    a     1         4
```

for each *item* I would like to count the number of distinct *user* at each *level* between the *level* (min value) and the *level_max*. So the expected output would be :

```
> data.frame(item = c("a", "a", "a", "a"), level = 1:4, count = c(2, 2, 1, 1))
  item level count
1    a     1     2
2    a     2     2
3    a     3     1
4    a     4     1
```

My approach is to "expand" the data frame to get one line per user, item and level :

```
exapanded_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, apply(x, 1L, function(x) { 
  range <- x["level"]:x["level_max"]
  data.frame(user = rep(x["user"], length(range)), 
             item = rep(x["item"], length(range)), 
             level = range)
}))
```

and then grouping and counting with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
exapanded_df %>%
  group_by(item, level) %>% 
  summarize(count = n_distinct(user))
```

But I have a lot of rows and the `apply` approach is not very efficient, is there any other option ? Thanks

Comment: `object 'x' not found` from the third chunk. Did you mean to give names to the first two DFs?

Comment: I can offer simpler but (3x) slower code: `mutate(x, level = map2(level, level_max, seq)) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  count(item, level)`. Though it is slower on this toy example, maybe you can try it on your real data

Comment: x refers to the first data frame sorry

Comment: @Aurèle Timings on the OP's example won't be meaningful since it is so small.

Comment: @Frank Added a benchmark on fake (and hopefully similar to OP's) bigger data

Comment: @Aurèle Thanks. Yeah, it makes sense to me that your way proves faster.

Answer (score 2):

We can expand the data frame and count the number like this, although it may not be the most efficient solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(level = map2(level, level_max, `:`)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  count(item, level)
dat2
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   item  level     n
#   <fct> <int> <int>
# 1 a         1     2
# 2 a         2     2
# 3 a         3     1
# 4 a         4     1
```

---

For benchmarking, we can fake bigger data:

```
set.seed(1) ; x <- data.frame(
  user = rep(seq_len(1e3), each = 26),
  item = rep(letters, times = 1e3),
  level = sample(1:5, 1e3*26, replace = TRUE),
  level_max = sample(5:9, 1e3*26, replace = TRUE)
) 

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  a = do.call(rbind.data.frame, apply(x, 1L, function(x) { 
    range <- x["level"]:x["level_max"]
    data.frame(user = rep(x["user"], length(range)), 
               item = rep(x["item"], length(range)), 
               level = range)
  })) %>%
    group_by(item, level) %>% 
    summarize(count = n_distinct(user)),
  b = mutate(x, level = map2(level, level_max, seq)) %>% 
    unnest() %>% 
    count(item, level),
  times = 5
)


# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#     a 33489.1391 36795.5105 36460.3686 37205.2517 37284.5728 37527.3690     5
#     b   407.6839   454.4582   461.4137   464.6317   480.3397   499.9549     5
```

And versus @Frank's approach:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  b = mutate(x, level = map2(level, level_max, seq)) %>% 
    unnest() %>% 
    count(item, level)
  ,
  f = x %>% group_by(item) %>% 
  summarise(level = map2(min(level), max(level_max), seq)) %>% 
  unnest(level) %>% mutate(n = count_matches(., x, item == item, level <= level, level_max >= level))
  , 
  times = 5
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#     b 500.72074 534.07906 550.55589 542.21577 570.87849 604.8854     5   b
#     f  36.15499  41.06282  46.11696  41.16352  49.21757  62.9859     5  a

# speeds differ because this was run on Frank's comp unlike the first benchmark
```

Comment: I tried this too but my benchmark on the example data says it's 3 times slower than OP's

Comment: @Aurèle I did not see your comment. I will convert this post to a wiki answer.

Comment: It's totally fine, we posted in the same 10 seconds

Comment: Fwiw, I have updated my solution and now see ~10x speedup compared to this way. I suspect that the reason is that expanding min(level):max(level_max) per item creates a much smaller table than level:level_max per item and user.

Comment: @Aurèle Ok, added. Sorry, I'd meant to add a link to the benchmark in my previous comment but forgot: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42387644#42387644

Answer (score 2):

```
# enumerate where we want counts
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
out = x %>% group_by(item) %>% 
  summarise(level = map2(min(level), max(level_max), seq)) %>% 
  unnest(level)

# count based on conditions    
out %>% mutate(n = count_matches(., x, item == item, level <= level, level_max >= level))

  item level n
1    a     1 2
2    a     2 2
3    a     3 1
4    a     4 1
```

where `count_matches` is a helper function:

```
library(data.table)
count_matches = function(DF, targetDF, ...){
  onexpr = substitute(list(...))
  data.table(targetDF)[data.table(DF), on=eval(onexpr), allow.cart=TRUE, .N, by=.EACHI]$N
}
```

If you don't want to use purrr and tidyr, the "unmodern" approach to that part would be

```
out = x %>% group_by(item) %>% 
  do({data.frame(level = min(.$level):max(.$level_max))})
```

(Disclosure: [I am reposting this helper function from yesterday.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50140399/)..)